# Send Data from a Raspberry Pi to a Webservice with a Python Script?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have a Webservice wich is reachable over a URL and I have a Raspberry with different sensors wich measures the temperature and co2.Now I want to write a Python script to send this values to the Webserver.

Comment: Welcome! Please read https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and maybe https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/53/ (PDF is for free).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at python-requests API. It's readily available as a dpkg package on raspberry pi's repos. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your web service is expecting a GET request with data passed as query string parameters, you would do something like this:

```py
import requests
payload = {'sensor': 'temp1', 'temperature': 32}
response = requests.get('https://server.example.com/webservice/endpoint', params=payload)
```

Similar with a POST request to an endpoint expecting JSON encoded data:

```py
response = requests.post('https://server.example.com/webservice/endpoint2', json=payload)
```

Tell us more about the webservice and I will edit the answer accordingly.